# Get row numbers of unique rows in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that has some unique rows and I would like to get the row names of those unique rows only.

```
m <- matrix( data = c(1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2), ncol = 3 )
```

Comment: Please note that you should provide expected output when you give sample input. In this case, do you consider the first row to be duplicated or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the expected row index is '3' as the other two rows are duplicates, then use `duplicated` to get the logical index and wrap with `which` for the numeric index.

```
 which(!(duplicated(m)|duplicated(m,fromLast=TRUE)))
 #[1] 3
```

If we consider the 1st and 3rd as the `unique` rows, then

```
 which(!duplicated(m))
```